# why isn't my loop running when the data gets converted to array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

```
   filename = "list.txt"
# in list.txt file seperate package name on next line to generate string

def splitter():
    with open(filename) as f:
      lines = f.read().splitlines()
      list = print(lines)
      return list

usrInput = input("Enter 1 for install or 2 for Uninstall list: ")

if usrInput == 1 :
  splitter()
  for ele in list:
    print('adb install "apk/%s.apk" > CON'%ele)

else:   
  splitter();
  for ele in list:
    print('adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 %s" > CON'%ele)
```

In this case I have a file called list.txt in which each seperate file a package name is written. the spitter function easily convert all packages into arrays but then it shows a error :TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable. I want loop to work and print the data to seperate lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example has a great introduction on how to create a minimal reproducible example. You have the code but a bit of data would be really usual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly don't use names like `list` for variables as these are `built-in`s. Secondly when you `return` something from a function you need to assign it to a variable to keep track of it.

Actually, in this case, you don't need a variable:

```py
def splitter(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
      return f.read().splitlines()

# in list.txt file separate package name on next line to generate string
filename = "list.txt"
usrInput = input("Enter 1 for install or 2 for Uninstall list: ")

if usrInput == '1':
  for ele in splitter(filename):
    print('adb install "apk/%s.apk" > CON' % ele)
else:   
  for ele in splitter(filename):
    print('adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 %s" > CON' % ele)
```

Also, your error message from: `for ele in list:` if referring to `list` being a type or built-in.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the return value from `splitter` to anything outside the function. What you need to do is use the function call inside the loop enumeration like `for ele in splitter()`. Also, try to refrain from using Python's reserved names like `list` as variable names.